# Do memberships in asp.net 3.5 and 4.0 use the same database schema?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I've done some researches without really finding what I'm looking for. The application I'm working on is an ASP.NET 3.5 **website**. I'd like to upgrade it to 4.0 **web application**. I know that most of the code will work.

My main concern is with the **membership provider**. Are both 3.5 and 4.0 use the same schema? there are already users in the membership tables. Is pointing my new 4.0 application to the same database will work or I need to make first some adjustment?

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

I've created a sample **web application** in 4.0 and made the connection string to point the existing database. When I try to log in with existing credentials, I get the following message:

`Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.`

When I check the **SQL Server profiler**, it seems like the call has even never been made to the database.

When I add this line: `var user = Membership.GetUser("username");` n the **Page_Load** method, I see that the following query was been executed from the profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Limit1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
    [u].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM   [dbo].[Memberships] AS [m]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [u] ON [m].[UserId] = [u].[UserId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Applications] AS [a] ON [m].[ApplicationId] = [a].[ApplicationId]
    WHERE (((LOWER([a].[ApplicationName])) = (LOWER(@p__linq__0))) OR ((LOWER([a].[ApplicationName]) IS NULL) AND (LOWER(@p__linq__0) IS NULL))) AND (((LOWER([m].[Email])) = (LOWER(@p__linq__1))) OR ((LOWER([m].[Email]) IS NULL) AND (LOWER(@p__linq__1) IS NULL)))
)  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'/',@p__linq__1=N'username'
```

Still it's not returning any result. What's strange is that I noticed that the table don't have quite the same names: tables don't have the prefix aspnet_, yet the the exhaustion of the query is not **throwing** an error even on the Management Studio.

Here's the config file section of membership:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, 
               System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
         connectionStringName="myConnectionString" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Thanks for helping. I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know they use the same schema. There is a table called aspnet_SchemaVersions where you can check the schema version but I've never seen anything but the record 1 in this table. Also ASP.NET membership works via Stored Procedures so even if they changed something your SPs will keep the old behavior.

Comment: On first look it looks like you are using the universal providers which are alternative implementation of the membership providers. You should use SqlMembershipProvider (basically copy your old configuration). I believe this provider created its own database somewhere for membership purposes.